# How to add Context Path to request URI?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, spring-mvc, tomcat7

The default path of my app is localhost:8080/myapp .

If I click something on the page which is supposed to redirect me to localhost:8080/myapp/page1 I get 404 back (The requested resource is not available.)
because the actual request made is localhost:8080/page1 .
Fair enough, my RequestMapping is "/page1". 
The question is how do I enforce the contextpath as a prefix to all requests ? 
What is the best way to deal with this ?

P.S. I don't want to rename my app to Root

Comment: Add your web.xml and your page where you have link for page1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using JSTL.

for example.

```
<a href="<c:url value="/page1" />">LINK</a>
```